# Go Lang Print Inputted Array

Tags: arrays, input, go

I am studying Go lang right now and I encountered a problem when trying to print inputted Array. My code is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    set(n)
}

func set(n int) {
    a := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Scan(&a[i])
    }
    for y := 0; y < n; y++ {
        fmt.Println(a[y])
    }
    return
}
```

my problem is when Inputted a number as a size for the array, that number always get printed too.
Like when I inputted 8 as the array size then followed by the array value for example 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 then I get the wrong output: 8 10 9 8 7 6 5 4.Iit should be 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Try just printing the whole array at once.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, what version of Go are You using? and what OS?

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/gHBNoy_HGN works fine

Comment: [@Exill](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3979885/exill): For the Go version and OS, post the output of the `go version` command.

Comment: I use Go version 1.3. and OS Windows + LiteIDE.

Answer (score 3):

```
package main
import ("fmt")
func main() {
  var n int
  fmt.Scan(&n)
  set(n)
}

func set(n int) {
  a := make([]int, n)
  for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
      fmt.Scan(&a[i])
    }
  fmt.Println(a)
 }
```

Comment: please add some description - over code only answer

Answer (score 1):

Can not duplicate problem yet.  For [example](http://play.golang.org/p/s3umygOubR):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    sampleInput := bytes.NewBufferString("3 1 2 3")
    fmt.Fscan(sampleInput, &n)
    set(sampleInput, n)
}

func set(input io.Reader, n int) {
    a := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Fscan(input, &a[i])
    }
    for y := 0; y < n; y++ {
        fmt.Println(a[y])
    }
    return
}
```

is a variation of your program.  It has the expected behavior: it prints the numbers 1 2 3 that it read into the slice.

Answer (score 0):

```
i:=0
var a[5] int
for(i<5){
fmt.Print("Enter Input")
var input int
fmt.Scanf("%d",&input)
a[i]=input
i+=1
}
fmt.Print(a)
```

This seems to work for me.Please refer.